# How to list Homebrew packages?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I am new to using the terminal on Mac Catalina.

When I enter `brew help`, it appears that brew is installed.

However, when I attempt to list the packages in the terminal with the command `brew search`. I keep getting this error:

> Invalid usage: This command requires at least 1 text or regex argument.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all available formulae run:

```
brew formulae
```

If you want to list installed formulae run:

```
brew list
```

If you want to search all available formulae containing, for example, the string "mariadb" run:

```
brew search mariadb
```